# match two files and filter out

Tags: text-processing, text

I have two files

file A

```
>TCONS_00000075 gene=XLOC_000030
CCGCCGGCTGCTGCGCGCACCGACTTGTCACCACCCCAGCACGTCCTCCACGTATACAAGCGCTACGGTC
CACCGCGGCAGCGTCGACGTCCTTGTCCGCAAACATGGTGGTGGCAGCTTCCTCATCGAGCAGCAGCAAC
TCATCCTCGAGGGGAAGGGCCCAGAGCTTCTAATCCTACACGGCAACAACACTTTATACTTGTGTATAAT
>TCONS_00013830 gene=XLOC_006942
AAACACGGTTAGCTTGATATCACTGATGATCGATGGGATAGAGTCAGAGAACATCTTGTTCCTTAATTAT
CTCAATTCGTGAGATGTTGGACGATATCTCGATAGGGAGAGAAGGCGTTGTTCTGGATCATCACCGTGCT
CAGGGGTCAATTTTACACTGAGCAGGGGCAAAGACGTAAATTTTTACTTCCTTACTTGAGTAAGAGCAAG
TTTAATACTACAACCAACTACTACAAACTCCAATTCATTTATAACCAATCTAATAACTTATTCATACAAT
AGTTACCTATAAGCATATACTACACACACAACGTATTGGAATCCTCCGTGCTGCTGCTGGCTACAGATCT
```

file B

```
XLOC_000030
XLOC_000059
XLOC_000210
```

FileA is a FASTA sequence file. Each line starting with `>` is a sequence name and the lines beneath it are the sequence. I want to extract the sequences of those IDs mentioned in FileB. In this case:

file C

```
>TCONS_00000075 gene=XLOC_000030
CCGCCGGCTGCTGCGCGCACCGACTTGTCACCACCCCAGCACGTCCTCCACGTATACAAGCGCTACGGTC
CACCGCGGCAGCGTCGACGTCCTTGTCCGCAAACATGGTGGTGGCAGCTTCCTCATCGAGCAGCAGCAAC
TCATCCTCGAGGGGAAGGGCCCAGAGCTTCTAATCCTACACGGCAACAACACTTTATACTTGTGTATAAT
```

I tried this command:

```
perl -pe 's/\n//; s/>(.*)/\n>$1\t/' A |grep -f <(awk '{print $1}' B) |sed 's/\t/\n/' | fold -w 60 > C
```

but it's not working.

Comment: "It's not working" What is not working? That is not a *a* perl command, it is a command sequence. Which programs of the four that you run does not do what you want? Make a **minimal** example of what goes wrong by throwing away 3 of the four steps in your commandline, and provide the input and required output and actual **for that step only**.

Comment: this command i am using returns the file A as output

Comment: @rahul questions on another site are not duplicates. In any case, that question is irrelevant, this is completely different.

Comment: @user106326 I just tried your command and it returns the first sequence of fileA, exactly as you want. How is it failing?

Comment: My answer to the duplicate question (the one with TblToFasta and FastaToTbl) will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
        grep -A 1 $line filea >> filec
done < fileb
```

Comment: The output is `>TCONS_00000075 gene=XLOC_000030` and that's simply wrong.

Comment: I wrongly assumed the patterns to match were on the same line as the required content, adding adding -A 1 flag to grep will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

### Tip: Use database tools for database work.

If you end up spending all of your time just working out the mechanics of looking things up as opposed to doing the lookups themselves, and your commands to look things up are long combinations of `perl`, `sed`, `awk`, and `grep` that start to resemble modem line noise, then it is time to consider *using actual database tools* for your *database* instead of cobbling bespoke queries together with *text-processing* tools.

```
select * from RNA where gene in ('XLOC_000030','XLOC_000059','XLOC_000210');
```

is a lot simpler to work with.

That said, have some text processing modem line noise.

### Don't duplicate work.

You are transforming your database on the fly from a multiple-line-per-record form into a one-line-per-record form.  Do that once, not every query.  Have a `Makefile` that says:

```
A.flat: A
        sed -e '/^>/s/$$/ /;:a;$$!N;s/\n //;ta;s/^>//;P;D' $^ > $@.tmp
        mv $@.tmp $@
```

Then just run `make` every time that `A` could have changed.  (Don't forget that `make` relies on that whitespace at the start of those lines being a `TAB` character.)

That `sed` program is:

```
# Append a space to the first line in the record.
/^>/s/$$/ /
:a
# Join if not EOF
$!N
# Eliminate newline and space if the joined line began with a space.
s/\n //
# Loop around if so.
ta
# Eliminate the initial start of record character, as that is now the line break.
s/^>//
# Print and remove the whole record from the buffer.  Then start again.
P
D
```

### Querying

You've over-complicated your query command, which is actually just

```
grep -f B A.flat > C.flat
```

Converting the query output back to multiple-line records is more line noise:

```
sed -e 's/^/>/' C.flat|fold -s -w70|sed -e 's/^[^>]/ /' > C
```

Omitting the intermediate files thus gives:

```
grep -f B A.flat|sed -e 's/^/>/'|fold -s -w70|sed -e 's/^[^>]/ /' > C
```

### And again …

To repeat: Actual database tools would be much better.  If you have a large number of records, which seems likely given what you appear (from this and other questions) to be doing, searches, insertions, and deletions are going to be very inefficient using the text-processing tools method.  An actual database could be *indexed on the `gene` field*, in contrast.